# Prism WPF AutoWireViewModel exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, dryioc

I decided to do an important demo app with WPF and Prism to learn something cool while doing it. Everything went pretty fine until I add a Business Logic layer (PartsAnalysis.Core) in between my UI layer and the Data Service layer. For some reason, I get this weird Prism.Mvvm.ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel exception:

```
    at http://System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at http://System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at http://System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at http://System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at http://System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at Footer.Views.Footer.InitializeComponent() in C:\Users\akahaei\source\repos\PartsAnalysis\FootersModule\Views\Footer.xaml:line 1
   at Footer.Views.Footer..ctor() in C:\Users\akahaei\source\repos\PartsAnalysis\FootersModule\Views\Footer.xaml.cs:line 12
```

**The view and the view model were linking fine before the Business logic layer was added.**

Here's the FooterView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Footer.Views.FooterView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Footer.Views"
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />-->
    <!--Todo: add localization-->
    <Button Command="{Binding ImportDataCommand}">IMPORT</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Through experimenting, I noticed if I remove the IMeasurementAnalyser measurementAnalyser injection (that belongs to the business logic layer) from my view model's constructor, I don't get that exception anymore:

```
public FooterViewModel(IMeasurementAnalyser measurementAnalyser, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
     _measurementAnalyser = measurementAnalyser;
     _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
     ImportDataCommand = new DelegateCommand(ImportData).ObservesCanExecute(() => CanImportExecute);
     SendMeasurementsCommand = new DelegateCommand(SendMeasurements);
}
```

This is how it's registered in the FooterModule:

```
public class FooterModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public FooterModule(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IMeasurementAnalyser, MeasurementAnalyser>();
    }

    public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {
        _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.FooterRegion, typeof(Views.Footer));
    }
}
```

And here is the module catalog:

```
    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog)
    {
        moduleCatalog.AddModule<PlotModule>();
        moduleCatalog.AddModule<FooterModule>();
        moduleCatalog.AddModule<CoreModule>();
        moduleCatalog.AddModule<DataAccessModule>();
    }
```

### [image: The dependency diagram between the projects]

I've spent several hours on it and I still can't understand what is wrong. I also tried overriding the convention and anything that came to my mind but no.

Note: I'm using .NET 5 in all the projects.

Comment: I think, you forgot to post `Footer.xaml`... without the code where the exception occurs, how could anyone debug?

Comment: @Haukinger I added the FooterView.xaml. It wires fine with the view model if I don't use the Business Logic layer so I would think that's where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because of my reputation but is there a possibility that an exception occur or something goes wrong in the constructor of the MeasurementAnalyser.
If I try to replicate your problem in a test app using roughly the setup of your demo app, if I throw an exception in the constructor of a service register as a singleton I will get my thrown exception and also the autowire exception with almost the same stacktrace